# how to make python do not change characters in my dictionary code?

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, character

My teacher give us a task to write a spell checker for any language we want except English
so i take Dutch because it is approximately near to English letters ..

```
import re, collections

def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower())

def train(features):
    model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model


NWORDS = train(words(open('dutch2.txt').read()))

alphabet = 'aäbßcdefghijklmnoöpqrstuüvwxyz'

def edits1(word):
   splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
   deletes    = [a + b[1:] for a, b in splits if b]
   transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in splits if len(b)>1]
   replaces   = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in splits for c in alphabet if b]
   inserts    = [a + c + b     for a, b in splits for c in alphabet]
   return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def known_edits2(word):
    return set(e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) if e2 in NWORDS)

def known(words): return set(w for w in words if w in NWORDS)

def correct(word):
    candidates = known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known_edits2(word) or [word]
    return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
```

dutch2.txt has the folow :
when I run it the output is

```
    *** Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:18:40) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***
>>> 
>>> correct("de")
'e'
>>>
```

which is really incorrect ..
 And the alphabet changes for other characters

```
import re, collections

def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower())

def train(features):
    model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model


NWORDS = train(words(open('dutch2.txt').read()))

alphabet = 'aÃ¤bÃŸcdefghijklmnoÃ¶pqrstuÃ¼vwxyz'
```

what should i do to solve the changing in characters 
I try so much but I can't

Comment: Could you make this runnable? I also *highly* suggest that instead of working on unicode code points (what you get from indexing a string), you work on graphemes. The easiest way to do that is `import regex; regex.findall("\X", "ëo")` using the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package. Your `re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower())` should thus become `regex.findall('\X+', text.lower())`, and you should split each result with the other command.

Comment: This is not Dutch, it is German.